# PHP / jQuery : Loading browser specific page

Tags: php, jquery

**UPDATE:**

The issue is that I am using a lot of Javascript & CSS3 enabled modules which also contain a lot of heavy javascript and images. If it is IE6 to 8 and in some cases even 9, I dont want to display those modules or display them using someother method. Using CSS property `display:none` or conditional stylesheets using `Conditional Comments` is not solving my problem as the page still remains heavy loading all the javascript and images.

Hiding them is not the resolution.

Hence I want to load a very diferrent layout with a very diferrent `<div>` and module position structure.

and that is why I want to load all together a diferrent page.

Kindly help with some code snippets.

---

I am a newbie at programming and need help. The issue is like this:

I have developed a template for my site and I am using many jQuery and CSS3 functions in it.

Obviously I am having challenges specially with IE. Hence I am seeking help in serving a browser specific page. What I want to do is:

1. Identify the browser and IF it is IE then it loads a variable page called ie.php similarly for iphone, chrome, safari, firefox and so on.
2. It will be great if you cansuggest me a php solution, However i am also using jQuery hence if there is a simpler and shoter method in jQuery even that is fine.

**PLEASE NOTE :** I am a very novice at programming, hence please help explaining a bit about the functions.

Comment: what differences are you going to maintain ? CSS rules ? page layout ? functionality ? jQuery handles cross browser very well for JS

Comment: Don't. Browser specific pages are not the way forward. Use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Comment: @ManseUK The this is that I am using a lot of Javascript & CSS3 enabled modules on my pages and If it is IE6 to 8 and in some cases even 9, I dont want to display those modules or display then using someother method. Using CSS property `display:none` is not solving my problem as the page still remains heavy loading all the javascript. and modules but just hiding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load different css/js files if the browser you can put something like this in the `<head>` to only pull in the desired css/js

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/excanvas.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/IEfix.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/excanvas.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/IEfix.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

alternatively you can look at the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] in PHP and see what comes through for the various browsers.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Well jQuery (and JavaScript) can easily check browsers. Check out [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

Then once you detect the browser, you can load `ie.php` (I don't know why you need to) with a simple `include_once()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather detect by feature not by browser. For this I recommend: [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr)

For dealing with IE you will find useful [Conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) - there is no need to use server side programming (and different template files) or JavaScript (may not be available).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read up about [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

you can then do (as an example) :

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are searching for a php-solution:

A simple [switch case](http://be.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) will do. (Or "if, else if,...")

Check for the users browser using the php [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function

Then, redirect the user to the correct page using [header.location](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Hope this helps...